# How to set password in mysql 5.7 with length less than 8 character in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I want to set the password with length less than 8 character in ubuntu 18.04, but even setting validation policy = LOW doesn't allow me to set password of length less than 8 character.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set the MySQL 5.7 password which has a length less than 8 character on Ubuntu 18.04

Even the least strict password policy requires a password to be at least 8 characters.  **What you want is not possible since your using MySQL 5.7**

> Under the default password policy, which requires passwords to be at least 8 characters long
>
> - LOW policy tests password length only. Passwords must be at least 8 characters long.
> - MEDIUM policy adds the conditions that passwords must contain at least 1 numeric character, 1 lowercase character, 1 uppercase character, and 1 special (nonalphanumeric) character.
> - STRONG policy adds the condition that password substrings of length 4 or longer must not match words in the dictionary file, if one has been specified.

Source: [The Password Validation Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/validate-password.html)